# Materializecss: Is there any class to make a text prefix to a text-input

Tags: css, materialize

I need something to prefix my input text in MaterializeCss. Although it provides '**prefix**' class to serve that purpose, it doesn't work properly when I need to add multiple words as a span. For your information,  I need something equivalent to Bootstrap ***input-group-addon*** *class*.

Code:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="input-field">
        <span class="prefix">Full Name</span>
        <input type="text" name="" id="" />
      </div>
   <br> 
   <br> 
    <div class="input-field">
        <i class="prefix material-icons">attach_money</i>
        <input type="text" name="" id="" />
      </div>
   </div>
```

[this picture shows when I use a single icon it works fine but breaks down in case for multiple words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wx5pz.png)

I highly appreciate your wise replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood what the materializecss prefix is. As it states in the docs, it is called Icon Prefix - out of the box they provide the ability to prefix with an icon:

> Icon Prefixes You can add an icon prefix to make the form input label
>   even more clear. Just add an icon with the class prefix before the
>   input and label.

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
  <i class="material-icons prefix">mode_edit</i>
  <textarea id="icon_prefix2" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
  <label for="icon_prefix2">First Name</label>
</div>
```

[image]

The span class of .prefix that you're trying to add doesn't exist in materialize - it is for the icon tag.

"Full name", the way you are trying to use it, as a clue to what the input is - would be a label element. A prefix allows you to provide information that adds to the input (such as a dollar sign) or a shorthand, for instance an email symbol.

You could custom code the same feature from bootstrap, but it is a very different element altogether - and you need to rephrase the question as saying the prefix isn't working correctly is not accurate.

https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html

EDIT:

If we dive into the css for the default, rather than using flex in Bootstrap, materializecss uses absolute positioning, because it is meant for icons that have standard consistent width:

```
.input-field .prefix {
    position: absolute;
    width: 3rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    -webkit-transition: color .2s;
    transition: color .2s;
    top: .5rem;
}

input-field .prefix ~ input {
    margin-left: 3rem;
    width: 92%;
    width: calc(100% - 3rem);
}
```

The icon is given 3rem width, and then the input is given 3rem margin-left to accommodate it. I've adjusted these values up to 10rem to make it work for your text input - but if the text was any longer or shorter, you'd need to manually update this new rem value:

https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/XWbgWKg

Comment: Thank You. I may rephrase but it's materializecss docs' shortcoming, they nowhere mentioned that "prefix" class is only for icon-prefix, they introduced prefix class all on a sudden, that's why one may assume that they have generalized prefix class. the might have named it as "icon-prefix".

//Icon Prefixes
You can add an icon prefix to make the form input label even more clear. Just add an icon with the class prefix before the input and label.//

Comment: @Mateen the section is literally called 'Icon Prefix'. The docs example shows .prefix being added to an icon tag. Nowhere does it show or say you can add it to a span. There is no need to prefix with "First Name" - they have placeholder and label for that. There is also no need to add icon- to the prefix, because they don't offer any other kind of prefix and this would simply extend the amount of code you need to write. This is classic Bootstrap mentality of adding erroneous class names. Adds to bloat. Materialize keeps it lean :) As you can see from my codepen, I have created it for you.

Comment: I love materializecss more but I failed to make something like this UI by bootstrap and this is where I can't agree that there no is no need to prefix with "first name" or others:
[https://i.imgur.com/5UPkXlh.png]
code: [https://codepen.io/shiponcs/pen/MWwoYwV]

What would you do If you need to create something like this UI, I appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: If I needed to make that element, I would just copy the element from the bootstrap docs (chrome inspector, right click copy element), and then go in and copy the styles too: https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/WNvOvEP

Comment: If you need me to be clearer, show you how to use inspector, explain each element in the example, let me know. You won't be a beginner for long :)

Comment: @Mateen it would be great if you could accept the answer as a) there isn't a class in materialize for text prefixes and b) I built you TWO codepens showing you how to manually adapt the materialize one to suit, and also how to recreate the Bootstrap version :D